# Wildfly 10 session replication behind AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, amazon-elb

I followed https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Clustering+and+Domain+Setup+Walkthrough step by step.

Wildfly domain looks good.
I can read succesful registration log in both master and slave hosts.

That tutorial explains how to configure load balancing with mod_cluster. Anyway, I'd prefer takin' advantage of AWS Elastic Load Balancer service.

Then, I tried all three types of LB (application, network, classic), but none worked with me.

I wrote a simple app to test my use case:

**Front servlet**:

```
@WebServlet( urlPatterns = {"/test"} )
public class SessionServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject SessionBean bean;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doGet");
        process(req, res, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doPost");
        process(req, res, true);
    }

    private void process(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, boolean post) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if ( req.getParameter("name")!=null ) {
            bean.setName( req.getParameter("name") );
        }

        req.setAttribute("name", bean.getName());
        req.getRequestDispatcher( "/test.jsp" ).forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

**Session scoped bean:**

```
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    public SessionBean() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SessionBean other = (SessionBean) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SessionBean [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

**View JSP:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>  
        <title>Session Failover Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>You are: <c:if test="${empty name}"><i>nobody</i></c:if> <font color="red">${name}</font></h1>

        <br/>
        <hr/>
        <br/>

        <form action="/session-failover-demo/test" method="post">
            Who are you: 
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" /> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ok" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml file has

```
<display-name>session-failover-demo</display-name> 
<distributable/>
```

Finally, I make my test:

1. Browse the ELB endpoint /myapp/test
2. Set my name through the html form
3. Refresh a couple of time and see my name (from session)
4. Stop my 'master' ec-2 instance and wait a minute
5. The ELB notice master is down and start forwarding requests to 'slave' instance
6. Refresh the page and.... my name is... nobody!

The session is lost. I see in my browser dev tools that JSESSIONID cookie value has changed!

So I don't know whether I should blame Wildfly domain configuration or AWS ELB. Am I missing something?

**EDIT** Master stdout: https://pastebin.com/XbtVrb40

Comment: How are you stopping the master node?

Comment: For testing purpose, I start both servers in bin/domain.sh. 
Then I simply CTRL+C to stop one of them.

Comment: Ok, when you are doing a gracefully shutdown (CTRL+C or stop command) the session is drained and is not available y the SSO replication. Try kill the master node (`kill -9` pid for example).

Comment: I tried with Apache + mod_cluster, too.
It's like the two nodes are not replicating sessions at all. 
How can I diagnose that problem? There are no errors in Wildfly logs.

Comment: Do you use the default "ha" or "full-ha" configuration?

Comment: full-ha. We're on Ec2, so I tried to use tcp stack instead of udp. 
S3_PING instead of MPING ( bucket remains empty ). 
I can't find a way to test and understand if the two nodes do communicate.

Comment: @Fabio B. Could you bring more details about the socket-binding used for "jgroups-tcp" and "jgroups-tcp-fd". I want to know what is the "Interface" attribute? When you start you servers, have you seen this in server.log :`INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel hibernate
....
....
Received new cluster view for channel hibernate: ` ?

Comment: No. I just have: `[Server:server-three] 14:15:14,270 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel hibernate`

Comment: I just edited the question with logs